# How to set Async="True" in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting this error

> System.InvalidOperationException: async operation canot be start at
>   the time

And the error offers to set 
`<% @ Page Async = "true"%>` for the page

Well, I am using Razor so I am wondering how  to set it in Razor in ASP.NET MVC?
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately you're not showing controller code, usually you should use `public async Task<ActionResult>` for asynchronous action methods. Note that `<%@ Page Async = "true" %>` only available on ASPX/webforms pages. Refer to [this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) for async methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found something related on your question. You can increase the queue size in the IIS if that doesn't solve, you have some more information in the below link.

> https://forums.asp.net/t/1859797.aspx?How+to+fix+Page+Async+true+in+MVC+4+5+